# EF Code First: Defining foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I've looked at some other answers and lots of articles but this simple part eludes me still.  I'm using EF code first 4.1 but am happy to move to a newer version if it makes it easier.  I have a main fact table like so:

```
namespace Spend.Models
{
    public class ExpenseItem
    {
        [Key]
        public String UniqueID_ERLineID { get; set; }
        public String ERNum { get; set; }
        public String ItemNum { get; set; }
        public String Parent_Expense_Item { get; set; }
        public String Card_Number { get; set; }
...
```

and several tables hanging off that which have many to one relationships with the ExpenseItems:

```
public class ExpenseItemAccounting
{
    [Key]
    public String UniqueID_Accounting { get; set; }
    public String ERLineID { get; set; }
    public String ERNum { get; set; }
    public String ItemNum { get; set; }
```

As we can see, the ERLineID in the second table joins to UniqueID_ErLineID in the first, so the 'conventions' I normally rely on don't work.  So I need to use a virtual ICollection - but I'd like it to specify these fields as the link. Any assistance on how to do this appreciated.

PS. I can't rename the DB fields at present.

@LUKE:

I applied the changes you mention, they make sense.  I get the following error however:

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException occurred
  Message=One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

    System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationType: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'ExpenseItemAccounting_ExpenseItem_Target' in relationship 'ExpenseItemAccounting_ExpenseItem'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.
    System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ExpenseItemAccounting_ExpenseItem_Source' in relationship 'ExpenseItemAccounting_ExpenseItem'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be �1�.

  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.ValidateAndSerializeCsdl(EdmModel model, XmlWriter writer)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
       at System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany[TSource,TCollection,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 collectionSelector, Expression`1 resultSelector)
       at EmailClient.Prog.getData() in C:\MF\Dropbox\Dev_LN_Projects\04_QA\EmailClient\EmailClient\Prog.cs:line 172
  InnerException:
```

This came when I tried the following linq query:

```
        var geee = (from e in db.ExpenseItems
                        from f in db.ExpenseItemFbtItems
                        where
                        e.Item_Transaction_Date.Value.Year == 2011 &&
                        e.Item_Transaction_Date.Value.Month == 8
                        select new { A = e.UniqueID_ERLineID, B = f.ERLineID.First() });
```

I actually expected to be able to say e.ExpenseItemAccounting.ItemNum or something like that - do I need to put something in the ExpenseItem definition to achieve this?

My model is setup with the following.  The base.OnModelCreating appeared via intellisense and I've tried it with/without it for the same result:

```
public class SpendDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ExpenseAttachment> ExpenseAttachments {get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExpenseComment> ExpenseComments {get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExpenseItemAccounting> ExpenseAccountings {get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExpenseItemFbtItem> ExpenseItemFbtItems {get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExpenseItem> ExpenseItems {get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExpenseItemViolation> ExpenseItemViolations {get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseItemAccounting>().HasOptional(e => e.ExpenseItem).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.UniqueID_Accounting);
    }
}
```

Perhaps I need to put the virtual ICollection in the ExpenseItem definition?  Or is it perhaps the other way around - say modelBuilder.Entity has optional ExpenseItemAccounting?  That sounds more intuitive to me but I'm (clearly) not very good at this so take it with a grain of salt!

Thanks again

Comment: the error you get here is because the navigation property uses .WithOptional, and your DB has a non-nullable key. You can simply change the modelBuilder to use .WithRequired and it should solve this issue.

Comment: also in your linq query you are doing the join yourself, you can just use the navigation property to do this for you and simplify your query eg from f in db.ExpenseItemFbtItems ... select f.ExpenseItem...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
public class ExpenseItemAccounting
{
    [Key]
    public String UniqueID_Accounting { get; set; }
    public ExpenseItem ExpenseItem{get;set;}
    public String ERLineID { get; set; }
    public String ERNum { get; set; }
    public String ItemNum { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your modelBuilder use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseItemAccounting>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.ExpenseItem).WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UniqueID_Accounting );
```

EDIT:

To configure the navigation property to have a collection on the other end you can simply add it like this

```
public class ExpenseItem
{
        [Key]
        public String UniqueID_ERLineID { get; set; }
        public String ERNum { get; set; }
        public String ItemNum { get; set; }
        public String Parent_Expense_Item { get; set; }
        public String Card_Number { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ExpenseItemAccounting> ExpenseItemAccountings{ get; set; }
}
```

then wire it up by modifying the model builder config as follows:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseItemAccounting>()
     .HasOptional(e => e.ExpenseItem).WithMany(e=> e.ExpenseItems)
     .HasForeignKey(e => e.UniqueID_Accounting );
```

This will wire it up so that the ExpenseItem will have a list of all child ExpensItemAccounting's, you could also add a singular version of this if that makes more sense such as:

```
 public class ExpenseItem
    {
            [Key]
            public String UniqueID_ERLineID { get; set; }
            public String ERNum { get; set; }
            public String ItemNum { get; set; }
            public String Card_Number { get; set; }
            public ExpenseItemAccounting Parent_Expense_Item { get; set; }
    }
```

and using the modelBuilder for config:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExpenseItemAccounting>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.ExpenseItem)
    .WithOptionalDependent(e=>e.Parent_Expense_Item);
```

i think if you also want the FK references wired up (not just the navigation properties) you need to do this in a seperate statement but thats a bit more fiddly.

Take a look at the MSDN page on navigation properties and how to use the modelBuilder as its got lots of good examples of advanced stuff.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295843(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for this.  No room to explain fully here - see my edit in the orig question where I'm experiencing an error.  Any further comments would be great!

Comment: @Glinkot yeah absolutely you can make the relationship go both ways, just use a lambda to specify your collection in the withMany. Ill update my post to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is changing ERLineID's nullable value to TRUE